# Kong expose 3rd party downstream API using JWT to authenticate

Tags: authentication, jwt, kong, kong-plugin

There is a 3rd party API, which requires API authentication for the application calling it using JWT token with refresh mechanism. The JWT token is for the application ( like client secret and key) and needs to be sent with each request, it will be the same for all the requests.

In Kong, it’s possible to add a static header to the downstream request and fetch the response. Is it possible to generate a JWT token at the kong level and add it to the downstream request, when the token expires?

I tried finding out on StackOverflow and kong documentation and found a lot of plugins for acting as an authentication layer for downstream services. I also understand that API gateways are generally not responsible for authenticating themselves to the downstream services, I was wondering if it is possible in this case, this will help us not to write a new application just to generate tokens and expose 3rd party API for the time being.

Comment: This is very strange that the gateway can sign JWT, are you sure seems very not secured. The JWT package used to validate the signature can be extended to sign the JWT.

Comment: yeah, looks like I have to write a proxy service, just to sign JWT.

Comment: I really don't understand why you are using JWT if your are not using any identity provider. If anyone can call the service, just remove the jwt check on the service instead of creating JWT bringing nothing

Comment: the API is 3rd party and public, they have JWT authentication for security on their side. We want to expose that API  to our mobile apps through our gateway.

Comment: So you cannot sign the JWT yourself, you need to get the JWT for one of their authentication endpoint.

Comment: yes, but now things are sorted, we have negotiated for a long-lived JWT token, which we can put manually. Thanks for your replies.